# BigQuery select, join from multiple datasets and avoid name conflicts

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Imagine I have several datasets and tables.

Format: `dataset.table.field`

```
dataset01.table_xxx.field_z
dataset02.table_xxx.field_z
```

I try to write smth like

```sql
select 
dataset01.table_xxx.field_z as dataset01_table_xxx_field_z,
dataset02.table_xxx.field_z as dataset02_table_xxx_field_z
from dataset01.table_xxx
join dataset02.table_xxx on dataset02.table_xxx.field_z = dataset01.table_xxx.field_z
```

to avoid conflicting names
BigQuery says that `dataset01.table_xxx.field_xxx` is unrecognised name in SELECT clause.

it complains about unrecognised name in join clause too.
Query works if I remove dataset01, dataset02 from `SELECT` clause and `on` condition

What is the right way to refer fields in such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
  t1.field_z as dataset01_table_xxx_field_z,
  t2.field_z as dataset02_table_xxx_field_z
from dataset01.table_xxx t1
join dataset02.table_xxx t2
on t2.field_z = t1.field_z
```

Comment: ok, so the idea is to use "fully" qualified name of table dataset.table_name in FROM clause, add alias on it and the use alias in query, right?

Comment: correct. aliases is the way to go